# Validar variable de tipo ajax en cakephp 3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

verán tengo tres variables en mi función de javascript que esta de la siguiente manera:

```
function search_person_report(){
var User_persons = $("#email_person").val();
var names = $("#names").val();
var lastnames = $("#lastnames").val();
console.log(name);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    url: person_report,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {User_persons:User_persons,names:names,lastnames:lastnames},
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        var result_person = "";
        $.each(data,function(i,item){
            result_person +='<tr>';
            result_person += '<td>'+item.usuario+'</td>';
            result_person += '<td>'+item.Nombre+'</td>';
            result_person += '<td>'+item.Apellidos+'</td>';
            result_person += '<td>'+item.fecha_creacion+'</td>';
            result_person += '<td><input type="checkbox" value="'+item.id_persona+'" name="id_person[]"></td>';
            result_person +='</tr>'
        });
        $("#resultperson").html(result_person);
    }
});
```

}

bien hasta alli no hay problema alguno, el tema esta que esas variables tengo validarlas es decir, si están vacías o no dentro de la función en cakephp para luego pasárselo al SP el cual me enviara los datos para mostrarlos, aquí el código cakephp

```
public function searchpersongroup() {
    $IdUser = $this->Auth->user('id_usuario');
    $user = $this->request->query('User_persons');
    $names = $this->request->query('names');
    $lastnames = $this->request->query('lastnames');
    if (!empty($user)) {
        $user = '%'.$user;
    }else{
        $user = null;
    }
    if (!empty($names)) {
        $names = '%'.$names;
    }else{
        $names = null;
    }
    if (!empty($lastnames)) {
        $lastnames = '%'.$lastnames;
    }else{
        $lastnames = null;
    }
    $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    $query_search = $connection->execute('CALL ser_search_persons_rpt_grupal(:_IdUser,:_User,:_Names,:_Lastnames)',[
        ':_IdUser'=> $IdUser,':_User'=> $user, ':_Names' => $names,':_Lastnames' => $lastnames])->fetchAll('assoc');
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        echo json_encode($query_search);
        die();
    }
}
```

Cuando realizo la prueba me muestra vació no se que este haciendo mal ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0):

Las variables que se mandan a un controlador CakePHP desde una llamada AJAX no se reciben en la variable  $this->request->query sino en la variable global $_POST.

De tal forma que tus variables serán las siguientes:

```
    $user = $_POST['User_persons']);
    $names = $_POST['names']);
    $lastnames = $_POST['lastnames']);
```

[Más información](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php)

De esta manera deberías recuperar correctamente las variables pasadas en el controlador.

Un saludo y espero que te sirva!